# SQL Server Synonyms Performance with Views

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005, synonym

If I have two databases and create a linked table (synonym) in one of them to the other one and then wrap that synonym in a view, will there be a performance issue?  The reason I want to do this is to have SQLMetal see the synonym and generate a linq entity for it.  The database are on the same server.  Also if I did this 100+ times, all child databases linking to a set of tables in a master database, would that have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah - shouldn't be an issue. The Query Optimizer says "What do you mean by this" all the time, and unless it comes across a procedure (or function with BEGIN/END), it'll keep going. Synonyms are fine, views are fine.

Comment: thanks Rob, I was hoping that would be the answer :)  That is going to make my life much easier